# WCF - System.Data.SqlServerCe was not found

Tags: wcf, sql-server-ce, windows-ce

I'm try to work on WCF to sync the mobile database with server database. I was using [this tutorial](http://mobileworld.appamundi.com/blogs/andywigley/archive/2008/12/08/building-a-sync-services-for-ado-net-solution-for-mobile-devices.aspx). When i try to debug I got '**File or assembly name 'System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3BE235DF1C8D2AD3', or one of its dependencies, was not found.**'. I try to remove the reference and add again but still the same.

Below is the screen short of System.Sata.SqlServerCE.
[image]

Comment: What *exact* version of SQL CE is installed on the target and what version is your app referencing?  Don't look at the References window, but look at the actual DLL properties.  The build number is what I'm wondering about (e.g. 3.5.**8080**)

Comment: If this is a x64 computer, both the x86 and x64 MSI packages must be installed.